# How to run dense_rank() function with condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my script:

```
UPDATE public.build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized normal
SET unique_code = concat_ws('.', normal.unique_code, d_rank.code)
    FROM (SELECT main.year_data
               , main.build_code
               , main.form_owner_code
               , r_normal.unique_code
               , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY r_normal.unique_code) code
              FROM public.build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized          r_normal
                       INNER JOIN public.build_analyzer_objectdatamain main ON r_normal.main_id = main.id
    )                                         d_rank
       , public.build_analyzer_objectdatamain main
    WHERE normal.main_id = main.id
      AND normal.unique_code = d_rank.unique_code
      AND main.form_owner_code = d_rank.form_owner_code
      AND main.year_data != d_rank.year_data;
```

There is a `ForeginKey` in `build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized` table for `build_analyzer_objectdatamain` table and `unique_code` field, that contains following value:

```
10.13.109.75.00
10.13.109.75.00
10.13.109.75.00
10.13.152.38.120
10.13.152.38.120
```

If i delete all the filters except `normal.unique_code = d_rank.unique_code`, it will add rank to the end of `unique_code`.

But I need to apply filters like - one group of unique values (per rank) is  ONLY values with various `year_data` from `build_analyzer_objectdatamain` table. But my filters does not working.

Is there is a way to apply unique rank only when the condition (various years for objects with same `unique_code`) is fulfilled?

**Update (sample data):**

`build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized` result before script execution:

```
unique_code     main_id
10.13.84.38.204 28864
10.13.84.38.204 28865
10.13.84.38.204 16161
10.13.109.75.00 17635
10.13.109.75.00 17637
10.13.109.75.00 17636
```

`build_analyzer_objectdatamain` result:

```
id  form_owner_code year_data
16161   11  2012
17635   11  2017
17636   11  2017
17637   11  2017
28864   11  2013
28865   11  2013
```

`build_analyzer_objectdatanormalized` after before script execution:

```
unique_code       main_id   year_data   form_owner_code
10.13.84.38.204.59  28864   2013    11
10.13.84.38.204.59  28865   2013    11
10.13.84.38.204.59  16161   2012    11
10.13.109.75.00.10  17635   2017    11
10.13.109.75.00.10  17637   2017    11
10.13.109.75.00.10  17636   2017    11
```

So, unique rank (59, 10) applies to objects with same year, but I need apply unique rank only when objects with different years.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Question updated. Hope I've got you right. Otherwise i'll update it again. Thank